# Transformation and its inverse transformation; when we can define inverse transformation?

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform, transformation, mellin-transform

Suppose I have some function with
\begin{align}
\tilde{F}[t] = \int dx F(x) G(x,t)
\end{align}
I want to know what is the condition for the inverse transformation of $F$, exists, i.e.,
\begin{align}
F[x]= \int dt \tilde{F}[t] K[x,t]
\end{align}
and if exists how to find $K[x,t]$ with $G(x,t)$.

There are lots of transformations such as Fourier, Laplace, Mellin, and in each case, the kernel $G(x,t)$ and $K[x,t]$ is somewhat well-defined and explicitly known.

What are the conditions for $F, G, \tilde{F}, K$ for which the above relation(?) [I mean transformation and its inverse transformation works] holds?